# Is there a way to limit cellular data down to 3G only from 4G/LTE in Win 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cellular-data, nokia-lumia-930, data-usage, datasense

I have a Lumia 930 running the latest slow branch tech preview and I recently upgraded my data plan from 3G to 4G/LTE. But now the phone is consuming battery like crazy even when I'm not really using it that much during the day. So I wonder If I could force it to use 3G and if I could switch to 4G again when I need it (eg. When watching Youtube or Netflix etc.) To reduce this ridiculous battery drain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this setting an be set by going to **Settings** -> **Network & Wireless** -> **Mobile & Sim**

From there, tap the link for **SIM settings** you'll then see an option to choose the fastest connection speed to use (which, on my phone, gives the options of 3G or 4G)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **settings>Network & Wireless >Mobile & Sim >SIM Settings >Mobile network> choose Highest Connection Speed(2G,3G or 4G).**

You can switch between 3G and 4G in this way, I don't know whether there is an app for this.